# In proving that two points are in same diagonal line, round(rise/run) == 1 doesn't work but rise == run does

Tags: python

I am a bit more than confused. I was solving this [CodeFights problem](https://codefights.com/arcade/intro/level-9/6M57rMTFB9MeDeSWo/description), which I boiled it down to the question **are the two points diagonally aligned?**

Coordinates are such that:
a1 a2 ...

The coordinates are in "chess notation":

> Each square of the chessboard is identified by a unique coordinate pair—a letter and a number. The vertical columns of squares from white's left to the right are labeled 'a' through 'h'. The horizontal rows of squares are numbered 1 to 8 starting from white's side of the board. Thus each square has a unique identification as a string consisting of two characters: the first is the column label, and the second in the row number.

So I calculated the slope and determined that if said slope was **1** then yes, they are aligned. I say that because the description of "chess notation" determines a square board, so diagonal slope there would always be 1, right? But it didn't work for three hidden cases (I can't unveil the cases it didn't work for). Then reading round I found that to check if two points are diagonally aligned you actually compare `rise == run` but how in the world is that any different from `rise/run == 1` ?

I just don't know.

```
def bishopAndPawn(bishop, pawn):
    # Rise is the difference in 'y'
    # Run is the differece in 'x' 
    rise = abs(int(pawn[1]) - int(bishop[1]))
    run = abs( string.ascii_lowercase.index(pawn[0]) - string.ascii_lowercase.index(bishop[0]) )
    return rise == run
```

For the `return` part, the following **did not work:** (keep in mind that when doing this kind of return one must check if `run == 0` first, since otherwise you'll get an exception when trying to divide)

- rise/run == 1
- math.ceil(float(rise)/run) == 1
- math.floor(float(rise)/run) == 1
- round(float(rise)/run) == 1

Comment: Do your coordinates start at `a0`?

Comment: I've editted and copied it over from the link description problem so that it's better understood here.

Comment: Are you in python2? If so, isn't it just the issue of integer division? Recall than in python2, 3/2 is 1 and not 1.5

Comment: Yeah I'm using Python2, I did not know that. I am adding the new test cases because even if forcing one of the dividends to float, it's not working.

Comment: Well, you know that `ceil`, `floor` and `round` are actually changing the value, hence these tests will be `True` for cases when `rise != run`.
You should try `floor(rise)/run`,

Comment: Well darn it. Now it works. But why? In the comparison does it just drop all that's behind the decimal point and compare? brilliant. Please post this as an answer so I can check mark it.

Comment: Why the downvote?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're in Python2 and your problem is that you're using integer division.
In that case, `3/2` is `1` instead of `1.5`. It is not the case of `3./2` nor `float(3)/2`.

Using `ceil`, `floor` or `round` will produce a integer but that's not what you want; quite the opposite: you want a number close but not equal to 1 to be distinguishable from 1 instead of snapped to it: `math.ceil(1./2)==math.floor(3./2)==round(2./3)==1`